# classic asp turkish characters not displayed

Tags: asp-classic

My website does not display Turkish characters when they come from the database.

Instead of the Turkish characters, question mark is displayed.

I already put `charset=UTF-8`, `ISO-8859-9` and `windows-1254` in the , and `Response.Charset = "UTF-8"` on the top of the page.

[link to check it out](http://www.kampuster.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to your output characterset you should also set your server-side ***codepage***.

You can set the code page to UTF-8 either 
- at the page directive :

```
<%@ Language="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
```

- or using the Response object :

```
<% 
Response.CodePage = "utf-8"
%>
```

If this doesn't help either make sure you have saved your classic asp with UTF-8 encoding. (pending your editor)

Comment: I already tried `<%@ Language="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>`. How do I check the encoding of a file?

Comment: @Efe the encoding of a file depends on your editor (Notepad++, Textpad, ...) but most editors have an extra option to specify the encoding when going to File > Save As

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to the same character encoding as your database

Comment: My database settings are `MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)` and `MySQL connection collation: utf_unicode_ci`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem

```
response.codepage = 1254
response.charset = "windows-1254"
response.lcid = 1055
```

Answer (score -1):

I usually write my code in Sublime Text (free version) and after having tried meta tags (charset=UTF-8, ISO-8859-9 and windows-1254) nothing seemed to work. I thought the problem might be Sublime text, so I transferred my code to Notepad++ and changed the encoding to UTF-8 in the top menu, saved it, and uploaded that file to hosting. As a result it worked.